# Training and validation accuracy sometimes get stuck

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Sometimes (50%~ chance) the training accuracy of my network gets stuck at 87% after the first epoch. I did not change any
hyper parameters or change the structure of the network. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: your model summary would help us.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being randomly sampled that is why you get this problem. Set the `seed` for randomization and check if the problem still persists.